# Delete TotalFinder Mavericks

Tags: applications, macos

since I updated to mavericks. I do not use totalFinder anymore. I deleted it first, but on every start i get this failure message.

[image]

I already searched the developer site for help. But nothing helped. http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/uninstallation

Do you know any trick how to delete everything from this application?

Comment: Did you use the uninstallation option in the menu of the application? Perhaps try installing it again and uninstalling it a second time will do the trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is probably a login item that is attempting to run it still in your user account.

In `System Preferences` select `Users & Groups` then your account in the left hand list. To the right select `Login Items` and browse the list. When you find `TotalFinder` click on the small '-' at the bottom of the list.

This should fix it.

If that doesn't work and the Uninstaller they give you doesn't work then I suspect their uninstaller is running into a permissions problem caused by the upgrade to Mavericks. I would try a reinstall and then uninstall.

Comment: I have not enough stars to rate your answer, but that was the solution to resolve the problem. Thank you

Comment: Thanks Tony, I was looking for the same thing for weeks...